# Error al cargar el servicio de laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola necesito ayuda estoy comenzando a aprender a programar con laravel usando laragon aún y al cargar el servicio en la terminal de laragon con el comando:
`php artisan serve` me muestra está dirección `<http://127.0.0.1:8000>`  y al ingresarla a mí navegador "Google Chrome" me muestra el siguiente mensaje:

```
Warning: Unknown failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 
Fatal error: Unknown: failed opening require 'C:\laragon\www\rutas\server.php'(include_path='.;C/laragon/etc/php/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

El nombre de mi proyecto se llama rutas.
Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: pues podria ser problema de version de `php`, o bien su **include_path** en php.ini esta en una direccion equivocada. Podria mostrar la version de php y vesion de laravel(tienen que ser compatibles), ademas de su `include_path` busca este en php.ini y muestras el primero que encuentre.

Comment: Tuve un problema como ese... y me dí cuenta que server.php había "volado". Algunos antivirus detectan ese archivo como pernicioso, y lo eliminan sin más. El archivo no tiene nada malo, pero el antivirus da un falso positivo y lo borra. Y he visto posts de otros que les ha pasado lo mismo.